# Combine 2 data frames with different columns in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, join, union

I have 2 dataframes:

df1 :

```
Id    purchase_count   purchase_sim
12       100               1500
13       1020              1300
14       1010              1100
20       1090              1400
21       1300              1600
```

df2:

```
Id     click_count      click_sim
12       1030              2500
13       1020              1300
24       1010              1100
30       1090              1400
31       1300              1600
```

I need to get the combined data frame with results as :

```
Id     click_count      click_sim     purchase_count   purchase_sim
12       1030              2500            100               1500
13       1020              1300            1020              1300
14       null              null            1010              1100
24       1010              1100            null              null
30       1090              1400            null              null
31       1300              1600            null              null
20       null              null            1090              1400
21       null              null            1300              1600
```

I can't use union because of different column names. Can some one suggest me a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
All you require a full outer join on ID column.
df1.join(df2, Seq("Id"), "full_outer")
// Since the Id column name is same in both the dataframes, if you use comparison like
df1($"Id") === df2($"Id"), you will get duplicate ID columns
```

Please refer the below documentation for future references.
    https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/faq/join-two-dataframes-duplicated-column.html